# can i run apex code via string received in a class?

Tags: apex

**I want to run an apex class where the code executed in the class will be passed via parameter, I couldn't find something that indicates how to do it.**

was thinking about something like this

```
String test = "assetItem.name = 'zero1' '';

for(asset AssetItem : AssetList){
//(something like)
apexExecuteCodeString(test);
}

update AssetList;
```

Comment: Doing so would be a glaring security hole. Strongly recommend against. You can get what you want in a much more secure way by passing field/value pairs (i.e. `{Name: 'zero1'}`).

Answer (score 2):

Technically yes, that is what the "anonymous apex" functionality offered by the developer console and sfdx does (and I believe there's a REST resource as well, which is what the dev console actually uses behind the scenes). However, the ability to execute code is something that should be *very tightly controlled*.

User input should never be trusted in general, and it should be trusted even less if people without programming education/experience try to write code. Allowing everyone and anyone to execute arbitrary code is several disasters waiting to happen (concurrently).

A more appropriate solution would be something like providing a button on a record page which ends up running an `@auraEnabled` method.

Comment: How would it be?